# 2d matrix composed from 1d matrices in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

A newbie question and possible duplicate: How can one compose a matrix in numpy using arrays or 1d matrices? In matlab, I would use following syntax for the matrix consisting of three arrays treated as rows:

```
A=[1; 1; 1];
B=[2; 2; 2];
C=[3; 3; 3];
D=[A B C]
```

The result is:

```
D =

 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 1, 1])
B = np.array([2, 2, 2])
C = np.array([3, 3, 3])
D = np.vstack((A, B, C))
```

See [NumPy for MATLAB users](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) (official link seems to be down)

Comment: Does it work with matrices? Let say I would like to compose 3x3 matrix using two matrices 3 by 2 and 3 by 1

Comment: The best way is to try it and see, but yes.